# fabric8 docker-maven-plugin: add additional tag on build from command line

Tags: maven, fabric8-maven-plugin

how can I add an additioanal tag on demand using the command line?

It's simular like question [44554857](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554857/fabric8-docker-maven-plugin-include-additional-tags-on-build), but I can't use that solution, because I need to pass the tag only in a view cases.